# Cython code 3-4 times slower than Python / Numpy code?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, cython

I am trying to convert my Python / Numpy code to Cython code for speedup purposes. However, Cython is MUCH slower (3-4 times) than the Python / Numpy code. Am I using Cython correctly? Am I passing arguments correctly to myc_rb_etc() in my Cython code? What about when I call the integrate function? Thank you in advance for your help.
Here is my Python / Numpy code:

```
from pylab import * 
import pylab as pl
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def myc_rb_e2f(y,t,k,d):

    M = y[0]
    E = y[1]
    CD = y[2]
    CE = y[3]
    R = y[4]
    RP = y[5] 
    RE = y[6]

    S = 0.01
    if t > 300:
        S = 5.0
    #if t > 400
        #S = 0.01

    t1 = k[0]*S/(k[7]+S);
    t2 = k[1]*(M/(k[14]+M))*(E/(k[15]+E));
    t3 = k[5]*M/(k[14]+M);
    t4 = k[11]*CD*RE/(k[16]+RE);
    t5 = k[12]*CE*RE/(k[17]+RE);
    t6 = k[2]*M/(k[14]+M);
    t7 = k[3]*S/(k[7]+S);
    t8 = k[6]*E/(k[15]+E);
    t9 = k[13]*RP/(k[18]+RP);
    t10 = k[9]*CD*R/(k[16]+R);
    t11 = k[10]*CE*R/(k[17]+R);

    dM = t1-d[0]*M
    dE = t2+t3+t4+t5-k[8]*R*E-d[1]*E
    dCD = t6+t7-d[2]*CD
    dCE = t8-d[3]*CE
    dR = k[4]+t9-k[8]*R*E-t10-t11-d[4]*R
    dRP = t10+t11+t4+t5-t9-d[5]*RP
    dRE = k[8]*R*E-t4-t5-d[6]*RE

    dy = [dM,dE,dCD,dCE,dR,dRP,dRE]

    return dy

t = np.zeros(10000)
t = np.linspace(0.,3000.,10000.)

# Initial concentrations of [M,E,CD,CE,R,RP,RE]
y0 = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.4,0.,0.25])
E_simulated = np.zeros([10000,5000])
E_avg = np.zeros([10000])
k = np.zeros([19])
d = np.zeros([7])

for i in range (0,5000):
    k[0] = 1.+0.1*randn(1)
    k[1] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
    k[2] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
    k[3] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
    k[4] = 0.35+0.05*randn(1)
    k[5] = 0.001+0.0001*randn(1)
    k[6] = 0.5+0.05*randn(1)
    k[7] = 0.3+0.05*randn(1)
    k[8] = 30.+5.*randn(1)
    k[9] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
    k[10] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
    k[11] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
    k[12] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
    k[13] = 3.6+0.5*randn(1)
    k[14] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
    k[15] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
    k[16] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
    k[17] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
    k[18] = 0.01+0.001*randn(1)
    d[0] = 0.7+0.05*randn(1)
    d[1] = 0.25+0.025*randn(1)
    d[2] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
    d[3] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
    d[4] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
    d[5] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
    d[6] = 0.03+0.005*randn(1)
    r = integrate.odeint(myc_rb_e2f,y0,t,args=(k,d))
    E_simulated[:,i] = r[:,1]

for i in range(0,10000):
    E_avg[i] = sum(E_simulated[i,:])/5000.

pl.plot(t,E_avg,'-ro')
pl.show()
```

Here is the code converted into Cython:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
from pylab import * 
from scipy import integrate

def myc_rb_e2f(y,t,k,d):

    cdef double M = y[0]
    cdef double E = y[1]
    cdef double CD = y[2]
    cdef double CE = y[3]
    cdef double R = y[4]
    cdef double RP = y[5] 
    cdef double RE = y[6]

    cdef double S = 0.01
    if t > 300.0:
        S = 5.0
    #if t > 400
        #S = 0.01

    cdef double t1 = k[0]*S/(k[7]+S)
    cdef double t2 = k[1]*(M/(k[14]+M))*(E/(k[15]+E))
    cdef double t3 = k[5]*M/(k[14]+M)
    cdef double t4 = k[11]*CD*RE/(k[16]+RE)
    cdef double t5 = k[12]*CE*RE/(k[17]+RE)
    cdef double t6 = k[2]*M/(k[14]+M)
    cdef double t7 = k[3]*S/(k[7]+S)
    cdef double t8 = k[6]*E/(k[15]+E)
    cdef double t9 = k[13]*RP/(k[18]+RP)
    cdef double t10 = k[9]*CD*R/(k[16]+R)
    cdef double t11 = k[10]*CE*R/(k[17]+R)

    cdef double dM = t1-d[0]*M
    cdef double dE = t2+t3+t4+t5-k[8]*R*E-d[1]*E
    cdef double dCD = t6+t7-d[2]*CD
    cdef double dCE = t8-d[3]*CE
    cdef double dR = k[4]+t9-k[8]*R*E-t10-t11-d[4]*R
    cdef double dRP = t10+t11+t4+t5-t9-d[5]*RP
    cdef double dRE = k[8]*R*E-t4-t5-d[6]*RE

    dy = [dM,dE,dCD,dCE,dR,dRP,dRE]

    return dy


def main():
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] t = np.zeros(10000)
    t = np.linspace(0.,3000.,10000.)
    # Initial concentrations of [M,E,CD,CE,R,RP,RE]
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] y0 = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.4,0.,0.25])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] E_simulated = np.zeros([10000,5000])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] r = np.zeros([10000,7])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] E_avg = np.zeros([10000])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] k = np.zeros([19])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] d = np.zeros([7])
    cdef int i
    for i in range (0,5000):
        k[0] = 1.+0.1*randn(1)
        k[1] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[2] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
        k[3] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
        k[4] = 0.35+0.05*randn(1)
        k[5] = 0.001+0.0001*randn(1)
        k[6] = 0.5+0.05*randn(1)
        k[7] = 0.3+0.05*randn(1)
        k[8] = 30.+5.*randn(1)
        k[9] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[10] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[11] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[12] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[13] = 3.6+0.5*randn(1)
        k[14] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[15] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[16] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
        k[17] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
        k[18] = 0.01+0.001*randn(1)
        d[0] = 0.7+0.05*randn(1)
        d[1] = 0.25+0.025*randn(1)
        d[2] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
        d[3] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
        d[4] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
        d[5] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
        d[6] = 0.03+0.005*randn(1)
        r = integrate.odeint(myc_rb_e2f,y0,t,args=(k,d))
        E_simulated[:,i] = r[:,1]
    for i in range(0,10000):
        E_avg[i] = sum(E_simulated[i,:])/5000.
    pl.plot(t,E_avg,'-ro')
    pl.show()
```

Here are some pstats from cProfile on my Python / Numpy code:

`ncalls tottime   percall  cumtime  percall`

`5000   82.505    0.017  236.760    0.047 {scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}`

`1    1.504    1.504  238.949  238.949 myc_rb_e2f.py:1(<module>)`

`5000    0.025    0.000  236.855    0.047 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py:18(odeint)`

`12291237  154.255    0.000  154.255    0.000 myc_rb_e2f.py:7(myc_rb_e2f)`

Comment: what does the profiler say about where the time is spent?

Comment: @Zhenya - I have never profiled before. Can you tell me how I would do this?

Comment: It would be much better to put the series of coefficients `1., 0.15, 0.2, ...` into a numpy array (`a`) and the `0.1, 0.05, 0.05, ...` into `b`, and then use `k = a + b * numpy.random.randn(18)`. and similiarly for `d`.

Comment: @Zack To profile your code you can run it with `python -m cProfile -o profile.dat <your-script>` then use `python -m pstats profile.dat` followed by the command `stats` to start making sense of the profile data. To view additional command help in pstats use the command `help`.

Comment: I ran cProfile on my script -- I copied some of the output lines which I thought would be useful for you guys: 

 `1    1.530    1.530  240.323  240.323 myc_rb_e2f.py:1(<module>)`

`12267587  154.889    0.00  154.88 0.00 myc_rb_e2f.py:7(myc_rb_e2f)`

`5000    0.024    0.000  238.539    0.048 odepack.py:18(odeint)`

`5000   83.554 0.017 238.443 0.048{scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}`

To me, it looks like the only thing taking my time is the integrate calls. Keep in mind, this is the profile on the Python / Numpy code - not the Cython code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the function definition to include the types of the parameters:

```
def myc_rb_e2f(np.ndarray[double,ndim=1]y, double t, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] k, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] d):
```

This will improve the running time about 3 times over the numpy implementation and 6 - 7 times over your initial cython implementation. Just FYI, I lowered the number of iterations so that I didn't have to wait forever for it to finish while testing. It should scale up with your desired number of iterations.

```
[pkerp@plastilin so]$ time python run_numpy.py

real    0m47.572s
user    0m45.702s
sys     0m0.049s

[pkerp@plastilin so]$ time python run_cython1.py

real    1m14.851s
user    1m12.308s
sys     0m0.135s

[pkerp@plastilin so]$ time python run_cython2.py

real    0m15.774s
user    0m14.115s
sys     0m0.105s
```

**Edit:**

Also, you don't have to create a new array each time you want to return the results from `myc_rb_e2f`. You can just declare a results array in `main`, pass it in on every call, and then fill it in. It will save you a lot of unnecessary allocation. This more than halves the previous best running time:

```
[pkerp@plastilin so]$ time python run_cython3.py

real    0m6.165s
user    0m4.818s
sys     0m0.152s
```

And the code:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
from pylab import * 
from scipy import integrate

def myc_rb_e2f(np.ndarray[double,ndim=1]y, double t, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] k, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] d, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] res):

    cdef double S = 0.01
    if t > 300.0:
        S = 5.0
    #if t > 400
        #S = 0.01

    cdef double t1 = k[0]*S/(k[7]+S)
    cdef double t2 = k[1]*(y[0]/(k[14]+y[0]))*(y[1]/(k[15]+y[1]))
    cdef double t3 = k[5]*y[0]/(k[14]+y[0])
    cdef double t4 = k[11]*y[2]*y[6]/(k[16]+y[6])
    cdef double t5 = k[12]*y[3]*y[6]/(k[17]+y[6])
    cdef double t6 = k[2]*y[0]/(k[14]+y[0])
    cdef double t7 = k[3]*S/(k[7]+S)
    cdef double t8 = k[6]*y[1]/(k[15]+y[1])
    cdef double t9 = k[13]*y[5]/(k[18]+y[5])
    cdef double t10 = k[9]*y[2]*y[4]/(k[16]+y[4])
    cdef double t11 = k[10]*y[3]*y[4]/(k[17]+y[4])

    cdef double dM = t1-d[0]*y[0]
    cdef double dE = t2+t3+t4+t5-k[8]*y[4]*y[1]-d[1]*y[1]
    cdef double dCD = t6+t7-d[2]*y[2]
    cdef double dCE = t8-d[3]*y[3]
    cdef double dR = k[4]+t9-k[8]*y[4]*y[1]-t10-t11-d[4]*y[4]
    cdef double dRP = t10+t11+t4+t5-t9-d[5]*y[5]
    cdef double dRE = k[8]*y[4]*y[1]-t4-t5-d[6]*y[6]

    res[0] = dM
    res[1] = dE
    res[2] = dCD
    res[3] = dCE
    res[4] = dR
    res[5] = dRP
    res[6] = dRE

    return res


def main():
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] t = np.zeros(467)
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] results = np.zeros(7)
    t = np.linspace(0.,3000.,467.)
    # Initial concentrations of [M,E,CD,CE,R,RP,RE]
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] y0 = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.4,0.,0.25])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] E_simulated = np.zeros([467,554])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] r = np.zeros([467,7])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] E_avg = np.zeros([467])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] k = np.zeros([19])
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] d = np.zeros([7])
    cdef int i
    for i in range (0,554):
        k[0] = 1.+0.1*randn(1)
        k[1] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[2] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
        k[3] = 0.2+0.05*randn(1)
        k[4] = 0.35+0.05*randn(1)
        k[5] = 0.001+0.0001*randn(1)
        k[6] = 0.5+0.05*randn(1)
        k[7] = 0.3+0.05*randn(1)
        k[8] = 30.+5.*randn(1)
        k[9] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[10] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[11] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[12] = 18.+3.*randn(1)
        k[13] = 3.6+0.5*randn(1)
        k[14] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[15] = 0.15+0.05*randn(1)
        k[16] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
        k[17] = 0.92+0.1*randn(1)
        k[18] = 0.01+0.001*randn(1)
        d[0] = 0.7+0.05*randn(1)
        d[1] = 0.25+0.025*randn(1)
        d[2] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
        d[3] = 1.5+0.05*randn(1)
        d[4] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
        d[5] = 0.06+0.01*randn(1)
        d[6] = 0.03+0.005*randn(1)
        r = integrate.odeint(myc_rb_e2f,y0,t,args=(k,d,results))
        E_simulated[:,i] = r[:,1]
    for i in range(0,467):
        E_avg[i] = sum(E_simulated[i,:])/554.
    #pl.plot(t,E_avg,'-ro')
    #pl.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: First, thank you so much. I tried including the types of the parameters to `myc_rb_e2f()` before I posted my question, but I was getting bad results because I was passing `np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] t` instead of `double t`. Changing to `double t` gave me correct results - why do you pass `t` as a double instead of as an array? Also, your speed up helps tremendously. My code went from 100s to 40s with your edit.

Comment: Good question. I actually didn't really look at what your program does. I just saw that you do the `if t > 300.0` check and assumed it was a double. Now that you mention it, it does appear to be declared as an array. I'm afraid I can't help you solve that discrepancy since it depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Also, how are you compiling your cython code? Have you included optimization flags? Those could improve it even further.

Comment: All this code is doing is generating synthetic data using randomly generated parameters `k` and `d`. I solve the system of ODE's many times and take the average `E_avg` of the time course of `dE`and plot it. I know what the plot should look like, and when I use `double t` as the argument, it looks perfect. However, when I was trying to pass `t` as an array to `myc_rb_e2f()`, I was getting the wrong plot.

I have a setup.py file. So from IPython, I do:

`%run setup.py build_ext --inplace;`
`import myscript;`
`myscript.main();`

That compiles and runs my code.

Comment: Yeah it's because the `odeint` function evaluates your `myc_rb_e2f` function for each point in `t`. So it iterates over the values and passes a double to your `myc_rb_e2f` function.

Comment: That makes sense. Any suggestions on how I compile? I'm very new to Cython and I'm just trying to follow an example online on how to compile it.

Comment: No that's how I did it as well (with the cythonize function).

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: I'm one of the core dev of the sub-mentioned tool*

As an alternative, extracting the `myc_rb_e2f` function to a single file and compiling it with [pythran](http://pythonhosted.org/pythran) yields a x5 speedup on my side.

The extracted python code (only a type signature) added:

```
#pythran export myc_rb_e2f(float[], float, float[], float[])
def myc_rb_e2f(y,t,k,d):

    M = y[0]
    E = y[1]
    CD = y[2]
    CE = y[3]
    R = y[4]
    RP = y[5] 
    RE = y[6]

    S = 0.01
    if t > 300:
        S = 5.0
    #if t > 400
        #S = 0.01

    t1 = k[0]*S/(k[7]+S);
    t2 = k[1]*(M/(k[14]+M))*(E/(k[15]+E));
    t3 = k[5]*M/(k[14]+M);
    t4 = k[11]*CD*RE/(k[16]+RE);
    t5 = k[12]*CE*RE/(k[17]+RE);
    t6 = k[2]*M/(k[14]+M);
    t7 = k[3]*S/(k[7]+S);
    t8 = k[6]*E/(k[15]+E);
    t9 = k[13]*RP/(k[18]+RP);
    t10 = k[9]*CD*R/(k[16]+R);
    t11 = k[10]*CE*R/(k[17]+R);

    dM = t1-d[0]*M
    dE = t2+t3+t4+t5-k[8]*R*E-d[1]*E
    dCD = t6+t7-d[2]*CD
    dCE = t8-d[3]*CE
    dR = k[4]+t9-k[8]*R*E-t10-t11-d[4]*R
    dRP = t10+t11+t4+t5-t9-d[5]*RP
    dRE = k[8]*R*E-t4-t5-d[6]*RE

    dy = [dM,dE,dCD,dCE,dR,dRP,dRE]

    return dy
```

compiled with:

```
> pythran myc.py
```

And imported with `from myc import myc_rb_e2f` in place of the function definition.

The original code runs in `103.46s` on my laptop, the one calling the pythran-compiled routine runs in `22.23s`.